# Which is the best standard to follow in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, code-formatting

Should i write the checking (or other condition checking) inside the rest controller or write in service function? What should i write in rest api & What to write in service class function? And also, is this checking is valid or need to throw exception if data not found? Example:

> Rest Controleer

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllEmployee(){
        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.getAllEmployee();
        if (employees.isEmpty()) {
            return RestResponse.generateResponse(HttpStatus.OK, true, "Data not found!", null);
        }
        return RestResponse.generateResponse(HttpStatus.FOUND, false, "Data found!", employees);
```

> Service

```
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllEmployee() {
        List<Employee> employees = employeeRepository.findAll();
        if (employees.isEmpty()) {
            return RestResponse.generateResponse(HttpStatus.OK, true, "Data not found!", null);
        }
        return RestResponse.generateResponse(HttpStatus.FOUND, false, "Data found!", employees);
```

Comment: Checking can be done either way but, I wouldn't return ResponseEntity from a service. Rather return an object to Controller and then encapsulate in the response entity if needed.

Comment: any problem if return ResponseEntity from a service?

Comment: There is no problem with it, as there is no problem with checking in service or controller.

Answer (score 0):

Any web application which follows the Spring MVC architecture, there will be usually three layers which will be defined.

**Controller classes as the presentation layer**. Keep this layer as thin as possible and limited to the mechanics of the MVC operations, e.g., receiving and validating the inputs, manipulating the model object, returning the appropriate MovedAndView object, and so on. All the business-related operations should be done in service classes. Controller classes are usually put in a controller package.

**Service classes as the business logic layer**. Calculations, data transformations, data processes, and cross-record validations (business rules) are usually done at this layer. They get called by the controller classes and might call repositories or other services. Service classes are usually put in a service package.

**Repository classes as data access layer.** This layer’s responsibility is limited to Create, Retrieve, Update, and Delete (CRUD) operations on a data source, which is usually a relational or non-relational database. Repository classes are usually put in a repository package.

So according to your requirement, you should choose the correct layer to write the logic.